# Setting a global python variable within a function

Tags: python, tweepy

I have a restful variable that I want to set to a global variable in python.

This code works. It allows the rest of the script to read the_api 
    global the_api

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
the_api = tweepy.API(auth)
print(the_api)
```

This code does set the_api, but in other functions the_api is undefined... Why can't I vset the_api from within a function in python.

```
def initTweepy():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    the_api = tweepy.API(auth)
    print(the_api)
```

Comment: You can always read globals out of scope, but you must precede any assignment of the variable with `global [my_var]` if you want your changes to be effective outside of the current scope.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [global](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) keyword otherwise python will create a new local variable shadowing the global variable.

```
def initTweepy():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    global the_api
    the_api = tweepy.API(auth)
    print(the_api)
```